# How to extract info from Jenkins console logs during execution to use later in same build execution?

Tags: jenkins, browserstack

I'm trying to implement polling of BrowserStack from Jenkins in order to keep the build execution open: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/polling-callback

During the build execution the console logs print the BrowserStack Build ID, and then the tests start:

```
12:27:38 Visit the Automate dashboard for test reporting: https://automate.browserstack.com/dashboard/v2/builds/abc123
```

I need to extract this Build ID 'abc123' to use later.

How can I extract this info, set it as a variable and use again in the shell command?

Use it like so: `$ browserstack-cypress build-info <buildId>`

https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/cli-reference#get-the-build-information

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback_url key in run_settings option in browserstack.json to get an update after that build is done running. The payload POSTed to this callback URL is the same as the one you get with the build-info BUILD_ID command.

Protip: You can keep polling the build status using the build-info command in a loop to monitor the build status, and then close the Local connection, and fail the build if the tests failed.

Comment: Do you mean the 'callback_url' can be any string? Rather than the exact Build ID URL?
Error from BS: callback url is : this-is-my-callback-url
Can you give me an example of a callback url ?

Answer (score 0):

The callback URL needs to be the URL on which the status of the build will be posted after the build is completed. You can generate a callback URL from  'https://webhook.site/' for testing. You will also get the build ID in the Payload.

Comment: Thank you, that webhook.site is a great help.